# How to use data from a custom field as expression in IF statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to maintain a number of rules in a custom post type.
A rule will basically contain the expression part of an PHP IF construct, together with some output content.

In my plugin, I would like to loop through these rules, and for each rule use the rule in an IF expression, and then if true, do something with the associated output content.

I plan to store the rule expression as a text field, but how can I take this text field and use it in the IF expression?

I have tried to add the expression to a variable in PHP, and then use that variable as the expression. This doesnt seem to be working.

```
<?php
// Basic idea


// Wordpress query ($args not detailed in this example)
$rules = get_posts( $args );

// Example of post_meta field: tmbd_rule
// Post A -> tmbd_rule = '$varA == 2 && $varB > 17'
// Post B -> tmbd_rule = '$varA == 3 && $varB = 28'

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $expression = $rule -> tmbd_rule;
    if ($expression) {
      // Do something clever
    }
}
```

So - I am looking for this run through the list of rules and "do stuff" when a rule/condition is met :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use phps built-in `eval()` function in order to evaluate the result of your rules.

Comment: Well, depends on context, but generally true!

Comment: He want a text field which is evaluated... Anybody who access that field can access than to anything (if he finds out this).

Comment: @golddragon007 - you are right. This is a risky proposal and security must built around it accordingly

Comment: @mynd - thanks for the suggestion. How would you approx use eval() in the shown example? Or would you suggest another approach?

Comment: OK, in case the CPT is accessible for others users, ignore my suggestion.

Comment: @KCarter With `eval` the approach would be relatively straight forward by calling something like eval(get_post_meta($postId, 'tmbd_rule', true), however as @golddragon007 emphasizes, it can cause severe security issues. So in case the context of using eval is not absolutely clear and limited to users who know what the are doing (basically not existing by definition) go for another approach as the other participants have suggested.

Comment: @mynd - as I read it, eval() is an output function. So I would then capture the output, check to see if that is true/false and proceed from there?

Comment: eval returns the result of the expression you are passing to it. So derived from your examples most likely boolean (true/false) results. So you don't have to capture "output" but simply the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from expression language it can be used without Symfony Framework as standalone library

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

For example(taken from docs):

```
class User
{
    public $age;
}

$user = new User();
$user->age = 34;

$expressionLanguage->evaluate(
    'user.age in 18..45',
    [
        'user' => $user,
    ]
); // true
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert - so where does the rule loaded from the DB come into play in you example?

Answer (score 0):

I can see now two options for this, which is secure. One what @Robert proposed.
Second, you create 3 inputs, two select list and a text field.
1 select list will contain the variable name. ('variable')
1 select list will contain the operation. ('operation')
1 text field will contain the value which is desired. ('value')

Than you need to match and build 'together' the condition with ifs.

```
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
  if ($rule->condition == '==' && $rule->variable == $rule->value || $rule->condition == '!=' && $rule->variable != $rule->value) {
    // Do something clever
  }
}
```

If you need more than one condition, than you need to group together and create a 4th field which says if it's or or and the connection between them. In this case the loop changes, like you check every condition separately, and than you looking for the second condition set (or/and) if it's fulfill your requirements according to your operation.

Comment: Thanks - but I am afraid that this gives a rather complex structure. Just in the above example, there would be a need for multiple variable, operators and values for one single rule. Can you elaborate a bit on your idea?

Comment: @KCarter Yes it will be complex structure. I can tell, and it's a hell to implement such a stuff. It's more likely a Senior thing and it might be hardly usable for the users... I just need to view the Drupal CMS, and I can see some part of it where this is implemented... Not an easy job if you want to make it secure.